# unable open C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py in windows10

Tags: kivy, python-3.6

I installed kivy using pip's latest wheels but I can't load `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py` in windows10. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is the error you getting?

Comment: i pasted a code that should open kivy in my machiene but it says an error that python:unable to open

C:\Windows\system32>python share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py
python: can't open file 'share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

When you install the kivy examples on Windows 10 using the following:

```
python -m pip install kivy_examples
```

or

```
python -m pip install Kivy_examples-1.10.1.dev0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

If your user is named "***usr***", the kivy examples are installed in the following location:

***C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\share\kivy-examples***

To run the showcase example, do the following:

```
python C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py
```

[image: Windows 10 - Install Kivy examples from a wheel]
[image: Installed Location]